# Internet Explorer not showing divs in a row correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I unfortunately have to support later versions of IE (10 + 9) and have a current setup with divs that appear correctly in all browsers except IE9. I have 4 cards in a row, IE 10 shows ok but in IE 9 the layout appears as so:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
.wrapper {
width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
}

.row {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -10px;
margin-left: -10px;
}

.row-show-4 {
width: 100%;
}

.card {
position: relative;
padding: 0 10px;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-show-4">
     <div class="card"></div>
     <div class="card"></div>
     <div class="card"></div>
     <div class="card"></div>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I know flexbox does not read correctly in older versions of IE, but can't figure out if that is the reason the divs won't display correctly, or if there is a fallback where I can keep flexbox as well for the newer browsers.

Comment: @c-c I think IE9 doesn't support [flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20flex)

Comment: @c-c, IE does not support flex, even IE also gives partial support. What I suggest you to use display: table on your ".row" and display:table-cell on your ".card". so you can achieve what you want.

Comment: found an [article](https://medium.com/css-mine/flexbox-how-to-deal-with-older-browsers-fbf6eb8c7a65), hope this might help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses everyone, what I ended up doing was setting a height to the card and it worked to solve the lone card showing up on a row on it's own.

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark this answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. I don't have access to IE9 or IE10 so you need to test this yourself.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

@supports (display: -ms-flexbox) {
  .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
}

@supports (display: flex) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
}

.row-show-4 {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left; /* Will be ignored in case of flexbox */
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px; /* To make it visible */
  background-color: gray; /* To make it visible */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-show-4">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-show-4">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
    .wrapper {width: 1200px;margin: auto;}
    .row-show-4 {width: 100%;column-count: 4;-webkit-column-count: 4;-moz-column-count: 4;column-count: 4;-webkit-column-gap: 20px;-moz-column-gap: 20px;column-gap: 20px;}
    .card{position:relative;padding:0 10px;width:100%;background:#c8c8c8;height:250px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;margin-top:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

After using bootstrap reference, it seems that it works well in IE 9, code as below:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .row {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-right: -10px;
            margin-left: -10px;
        }

        .row-show-4 {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .card {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 10px;
            float: left;
            width: 24%;
            background-color: gray;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row row-show-4">
            <div class="card">AA</div>
            <div class="card">BB</div>
            <div class="card">CC</div>
            <div class="card">DD</div>
            <div class="card">AA</div>
            <div class="card">BB</div>
            <div class="card">CC</div>
            <div class="card">DD</div>
            <div class="card">AA</div>
            <div class="card">BB</div>
            <div class="card">CC</div>
            <div class="card">DD</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The output like this:

[image]